# What does "synonym" mean in Java?

Tags: java, synonym

I read the JAVA API Document from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/. For calendar class, there is the following paragraph:

> DAY_OF_MONTH
>
> public static final int DAY_OF_MONTH
>
> Field number for get and set indicating the day of the month. This is a synonym for DATE. The first day of the month has value 1.
>
> See Also:
>
> DATE, Constant Field Values

I hardly understand the description, especially confused by the word "synonym". I will really appreciate it if anyone could explain this paragraph to me.

Comment: there is no special meaning in Java, generally a synonym is `a word having the same or nearly the same meaning as another`

Comment: @ThomasJungblut you should make that an answer

Comment: This honestly sounds more like a question in English rather than programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an English Language question.

Comment: How could this be an English language question? DAY_OF_MONTH is a static final variable, a constant, which equals integer 5. If DAY_OF_MONTH is a synonym of DATE, doesn't it mean DATE also a constant which equals 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Synonym means having same meaning.

In the source code of `Calendar`:

```
/**
 * Field number for <code>get</code> and <code>set</code> indicating the
 * day of the month. This is a synonym for <code>DAY_OF_MONTH</code>.
 * The first day of the month has value 1.
 *
 * @see #DAY_OF_MONTH
 */
public final static int DATE = 5;

/**
 * Field number for <code>get</code> and <code>set</code> indicating the
 * day of the month. This is a synonym for <code>DATE</code>.
 * The first day of the month has value 1.
 *
 * @see #DATE
 */
public final static int DAY_OF_MONTH = 5;
```

**Here both values are 5, so both are same.**

Comment: I always though DATE was some kind of class or even interface... never expected it would also be a constant... Thanks a lot!

Comment: I suggest you to use IntelliJ Idea IDE, where you can easily look the source code of any class by pressing ctrl+click. And if my answer answers your question, mark the answer as accepted. @JingHe

Answer (score 4):

A [*synonym* is](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/synonym):

> *synonym* **noun**.
>   1. a word having the same or nearly the same meaning as another in the language, as happy, joyful, elated. A dictionary of synonyms and antonyms (or opposites).
>   2. (...)

So it means something has a **different (field)name** to refer to the **same thing**.

So the documentation specifies that if you call `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` or `Calendar.DATE`. you will **always obtain the same value**.

We can verify this when we look at the [documentation for **`Calendar`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

> **`static int DATE`**
>
> Field number for get and set indicating the day of the month.
>
> **`static int DAY_OF_MONTH`**
>
> Field number for get and set indicating the day of the month.

The documentation for **both fieds is exactly the same**.